# Frida, Frida-tools, Android version Problems

Tags: android, python, frida

I have this environment..

- android : 9 version
- python : 2.7.12

I am not sure which version of Frida and Frida-tools I need to use to be compatible.
I'm currently using 12.8.5, but an ascii codec error keeps occurring, possibly due to incompatibility.
If you know a way to solve this or a suitable compatible version, please let me know.

please. thank you ;-0
ps. I have no intention of upgrading a Python version.

Comment: Make sure to use the same frida version on the PC side as well as on Android (frida-server). Anyway Python 3 can be installed in parallel to Python 2 so there is no "upgrade" necessary. You could keep your python 2 environment for whatever you need it and use latest frida on Python 3.

Comment: Thanks you. I found compatible Frida and Frida-tools version.